# Two of four fluorescent bulbs won’t light

Tags: lighting

Two of 4 bulbs are out in a 48” fluorescent light fixture. New bulbs don’t light.  Fixture has 2 ballasts.  One lights 4 holders on one end and one lights 4 on the other.  How do I tell if it’s a ballast problem or a holder problem?

Answer (score 2):

One of the ballasts has failed. Time to replace both.  Switch to T8 ballasts and tubes.  If it has 2 blue 2 red 2 yellow wires, you want a rapid-start or programmed-start ballast. The wiring will be simpler.

"One lights 4 holders on one end" no, that's not how the wiring is done.   Look closer and take care not to mix up the wires.  Generally best to replace one ballast at a time.

If you want to switch to LED "tubes", use universal, or direct-wire double-ended "tubes".  Gather all wires from all holders on one end, and connect them to hot.  Gather all wires from all holders on the other end, and connect them to neutral.